# How to recode some character values in a dataframe that start with specific letters and numbers?

Tags: r, dataframe, character, data-conversion

Let's say I have this df

```
df = data.frame(x = c("S112","S222","S232","S113","S103","S104"),
                y = c("S115","S242","S252","S117","S108","S110")
                )
```

I wish to obtain the following result

```
     x    y
1 lung lung
2 S222 S242
3 S232 S252
4 lung lung
5 lung lung
6 lung lung
```

The condition is that : for each value that starts with `S11` or `S10`, I wish it to be converted to the value `lung`

Comment: Take a look at the linked posts. Try `df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(grepl("^S11|^S10", .x), "lung", .x)))`